# X11 behaviour without window manager

Tags: window, x11

I am working on a system on which I want to prevent the end user from moving/resizing windows. Therefore I am currently starting a X11 server and my graphical application (named app1) without a window manager.

Now I need to start another graphical application (app2) on top of app1.
I've done some tests and it seems that X11 behavior is to stack each new created window on top of the previous ones. Also clicking on a window do not make it focus or change it's "z" position relatively to other windows.

I was wondering if this is the default X11 behaviour (is it documented somewhere ?) and if it is tunable ?

Mika

Comment: What are you using more besides X11? Do you have xterm and twm installed? "twm" is a Window Manager.

Comment: Okay, so you want to use a Window Manager but handle stop the "moving/resizing" things from outside the WM. Like a global change that will affect all WM's?

Comment: In fact I do NOT want to use a window manager. I'd like to know what is the X11 server behavior for managing window without a window manager.

Comment: So you want to handle the windows without a manager that handles the windows? That's impossible. If windows should be able to appear then something/someone needs to handle them, maybe themself or another window manager. You could of course code your own window manager but then you would still have a window manager.

Comment: I do not want to handle the windows myself, I just want to know what is the default behavior (without window manager) and if it is compatible with my requirements.

Comment: Have you read about "https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Manually" and also the manual pages that exists? Like "man Xserver"? Also the following page might help you "http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/". Google "X11" or "Xorg" or "XServer" followed by "documentaion" and maybe "linux" to find some useful pages. "http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/stacking-order.html" "http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/"

Comment: "what is the X11 server behavior for managing window without a window manager". There's none. A window manager manages window.

Comment: Indeed there is a behavior without window manager since you can display window without having one running. That's not because a window manager is always started on common distributions that you can't live without one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question has some problems.  The X server doesn't manage windows.  It seems like the last one mapped gets all the focus and stacks on top.  What it sounds like you actually want to do here is make your own WM that doesn't handle much.  There are so many WMs around, that do things so many different ways, and can be customized so much, though, that you could probably find one that suits your needs.  Compiz by itself, for instance, doesn't provide any window decorations and you can disable pretty much every keyboard and mouse binding and set focus policies and window placement in a number of ways.  There are also some WMs like "Awesome" and "ratpoison" that I think just tile windows and can probably be set up to be pretty invisible.  Basically, if you will have two windows that will both need things like keyboard/mouse input, they need to be managed somehow, and that's done with a window manager.

Comment: In fact, this is not 100% correct. Window manager providers user-side interface and decorations, while there is still api and way to provide so-called client-side decorations. Input is managed outside of WM, but WM may affect focus. It is just low level and most of frameworks do not provide any interface for that.The way it is explained by fact that X11 is indeed a server, the GUI may be rendered on machine different from one on which program is running, even a different platform (e.g. Windows). Having client-side decorations is considered faux pas because of lag and portability